# check size of image on checkbox click

Tags: android

I have a GridView which shows all the images from phone. I'm able to select multiple images and save the selected images to arraylist. I want to restrict the size of the selected images to 1MB. For that I want to check the size of every image while selecting. If the size of clicked image is less than 1MB then it will get selected, otherwise not. Is there any way to do that?

**Activity**

```css
public class CustomGalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static Button selectImages;
    private static GridView galleryImagesGridView;
    private static ArrayList<String> galleryImageUrls;
    private static GridViewAdapter imagesAdapter;
    int file_size;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.customgallery_activity);
        initViews();
        setListeners();
        fetchGalleryImages();
        setUpGridView();
    }

    //Init all views
    private void initViews() {
        selectImages = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectImagesBtn);
        galleryImagesGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.galleryImagesGridView);

    }

    //fetch all images from gallery
    private void fetchGalleryImages() {
        final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};//get all columns of type images
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;//order data by date
        Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                null, orderBy + " DESC");//get all data in Cursor by sorting in DESC order

        galleryImageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();//Init array


        //Loop to cursor count
        for (int i = 0; i < imagecursor.getCount(); i++) {
            imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
            int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);//get column index

            galleryImageUrls.add(imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex));//get Image from column index
            System.out.println("Array path" + galleryImageUrls.get(i));


        }


    }

    //Set Up GridView method
    private void setUpGridView() {
        imagesAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(CustomGalleryActivity.this, galleryImageUrls);
        galleryImagesGridView.setAdapter(imagesAdapter);
    }

    //Set Listeners method
    private void setListeners() {
        selectImages.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    //Show hide select button if images are selected or deselected
    public void showSelectButton() {
        ArrayList<String> selectedItems = imagesAdapter.getCheckedItems();
        if (selectedItems.size() > 0) {
            selectImages.setText(selectedItems.size() + " - Images Selected");
            selectImages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else
            selectImages.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.selectImagesBtn:

                //When button is clicked then fill array with selected images
                ArrayList<String> selectedItems = imagesAdapter.getCheckedItems();

                //Send back result to MainActivity with selected images
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra(UploadActivity.CustomGalleryIntentKey, selectedItems.toString());//Convert Array into string to pass data
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);//Set result OK
                finish();//finish activity
                break;

        }

    }
}
```

```html
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> imageUrls;
    private SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> imageUrls) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
        mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
    }

    //Method to return selected Images
    public ArrayList<String> getCheckedItems() {
        ArrayList<String> mTempArry = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < imageUrls.size(); i++) {
            if (mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                mTempArry.add(imageUrls.get(i));
            }
        }

        return mTempArry;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.size();
        //return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return imageUrls.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (view == null)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customgridview_item, viewGroup, false);//Inflate layout

        CheckBox mCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.selectCheckBox);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.galleryImageView);




        Picasso.with(context).load("file://" + imageUrls.get(position)).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(imageView);

        mCheckBox.setTag(position);//Set Tag for CheckBox
        mCheckBox.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(position));
        mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);
        return view;
    }

    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            System.out.println("sammy_position "+buttonView.getTag());

            
   File f = new File(imageUrls.get((Integer) buttonView.getTag()));
            int file_size = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(f.length() / (1024*1024)));

            // Filtering the image size
            if(file_size<1){
                mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);//Insert selected checkbox value inside boolean array
                ((CustomGalleryActivity) context).showSelectButton();//call custom gallery activity method
            }else{
                buttonView.setChecked(false);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Select image of size 1MB or less", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
    };
}
```

Comment: you can get EXIF info of images . So get all details and store it locally and check on click of item

Comment: I'm getting size of all the images in the gridview. But how to check size of the selected image on checkbox click?

Comment: Well what is the problem and what is the diference? You could explain that first. You should just check the size of the image file in the on check changed handler and if the size is too big uncheck right away. A better alternative is not to display such images to begin with. Or dont enable them or mark them differently. The user will otherwise hate this trial and error.

Comment: I want to check the size of selected images and if its greater than 1MB, it will not get checked @greenapps

Comment: Yes i had understood that right away. And so i told you how to do that. Why are you not reacting on my suggestion? Why dont you answer my questions? Why dont you tell what problems you have to do so?

Comment: Problem is how to get the image in checkchangedlistener using getTag(position)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public void calculateImageSize(int imageId){
        Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                imageId);


        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapOrg;
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();
        long lengthbmp = imageInByte.length;

        double sizeInKB=(lengthbmp/1024);
        double sizeInMB=(lengthbmp/(1024*1024));

        Log.d("TAG","Size  "+sizeInKB+"KB");
        Log.d("TAG","Size  "+sizeInMB+"MB");

    }
```

Replace Adapter With this

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> imageUrls;
    private SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray;
    private boolean isCustomGalleryActivity;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> imageUrls, boolean isCustomGalleryActivity) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
        this.isCustomGalleryActivity = isCustomGalleryActivity;
        mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
    }

    //Method to return selected Images
    public ArrayList<String> getCheckedItems() {
        ArrayList<String> mTempArry = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < imageUrls.size(); i++) {
            if (mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                mTempArry.add(imageUrls.get(i));
            }
        }

        return mTempArry;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.size();
        //return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return imageUrls.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (view == null)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customgridview_item, viewGroup, false);//Inflate layout

        CheckBox mCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.selectCheckBox);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.galleryImageView);

        //If Context is MainActivity then hide checkbox
        if (!isCustomGalleryActivity)
            mCheckBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Picasso.with(context).load("file://" + imageUrls.get(position)).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(imageView);

        mCheckBox.setTag("file://" + imageUrls.get(position));
        mCheckBox.setId(position);//Set Tag for CheckBox
        mCheckBox.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(position));
        mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);
        return view;
    }

    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getId(), isChecked);//Insert selected checkbox value inside boolean array

            String imagePath = (String) buttonView.getTag();
            ((CustomGalleryActivity) context).showSelectButton();//call custom gallery activity method
        }
    };
}
```

Use this function to find out the size in kb & MB

Comment: What's `imageId` here? @Mohit

Comment: i.e R.drawable.ic_launcher

Comment: My images are in device. What should be the parameter inside checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener?

Comment: @SomnathPal you will get imagePath from getTag() method

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got the path and also applied the check for file size. I'm accepting your answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: @SomnathPal i am glad to help you